# Ruby conditional class name

Tags: ruby

I have this snippet, but I'm looking for a way to make this more ruby like, DRY, etc.

```
if proxy_uri.scheme =~ /^socks/
  Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy(proxy_uri.host, proxy_uri.port, http_proxy_user(proxy_uri), http_proxy_pass(proxy_uri))
else
  Net::HTTP.Proxy(proxy_uri.host, proxy_uri.port, http_proxy_user(proxy_uri), http_proxy_pass(proxy_uri))
end
```

Comment: What does this snippet do? It's hard to understand without any explanation.

Comment: Its from a section of a method that returns an instance of `Net::HTTP`.  The class methods `Proxy` and `SOCKSProxy` (from socksify gem) work like Net:HTTP but pass traffic through a specified proxy server.

Comment: Those aren't class names, they are method calls. You can see that easily because they take arguments, and method calls are the only things in Ruby allowed to take arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much more to DRY, except the parameters :

```
params = [ proxy_uri.host, proxy_uri.port, http_proxy_user(proxy_uri), http_proxy_pass(proxy_uri) ]

if proxy_uri.scheme =~ /\Asocks/
  Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy(*params)
else
  Net::HTTP.Proxy(*params)
end
```

If you want to be fancy (untested):

```
params       = [ proxy_uri.host, proxy_uri.port, http_proxy_user(proxy_uri), http_proxy_pass(proxy_uri) ]
proxy_method = proxy_uri.scheme =~ /\Asocks/ ? :SOCKSProxy : :Proxy
proxy        = Net::HTTP.method(proxy_method).call(params)
```

Note that `Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy` and `Net::HTTP.Proxy` are capitalized methods, not classes.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also do things like `case proxy_uri.scheme` with a clause like `when /\Asocks/`. Using `\A` is preferable to `^` since it anchors to beginning of string, not beginning of line which can be a huge deal in some cases. You should also be able to use `send` with arguments being either `:SOCKSProxy` or `:Proxy`. The `Net::HTTP` library is extremely quirky and uses capitals in all sorts of inappropriate ways.

Answer (score 1):

`SOCKSProxy` and `Proxy` are function names on the `Net::HTTP` module.

This is that one weird trick to make a factory function look like a constructor. Ruby enforces class names to start with uppercase and variable to start with with lowercase, but methods are free to use either including module functions. See also `Array` class vs global `Array` function (which defined as a module function on `Kernel` which is included in `Object` and thus becomes a private method that's always available).

Thus try this,

```
Net::HTTP.method(proxy_uri.scheme =~ /^socks/ ? :SOCKSProxy, :Proxy).call(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do

```
proxy_uri.scheme =~ /^socks/ ? Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy(proxy_uri.host, proxy_uri.port, http_proxy_user(proxy_uri), http_proxy_pass(proxy_uri)) : Net::HTTP.Proxy(proxy_uri.host, proxy_uri.port, http_proxy_user(proxy_uri), http_proxy_pass(proxy_uri))
```

Comment: How can I format it to look like code? I'm on my smartphone

Comment: Edited. On a smartphone, I think you could add a newline a 4 spaces as indent.